# MongoDB Document - how to convert into model class?

Tags: java, mongodb, list, kotlin, bson

I have the following java code that I am using to paginated a response from mongodb, that works as expected:

```
List<Document> documents = collection.find()
        .skip(offset)
        .limit(limit)
        .into(new ArrayList<>());
```

Instead of a generic `org.bson.Document` what I want to return is a list of my specific `model` kotlin class Person.

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
class Person {

    @JsonProperty("id")
    var id: Long? = null

    @JsonProperty("name")
    var name: String? = null
    
}
```

When I try the following:

```
    List<Person> documents = collection.find()
            .skip(offset)
            .limit(limit)
            .into(new ArrayList<Person>());
```

I get compile error:

```
Inferred type 'A' for type parameter 'A' is not within its bound; should implement 'java.util.Collection<? super org.bson.Document>'
```

How can I resolve this?

The library used here is: `org.mongodb:bson:3.12.1`

Comment: i didn't found a direct solution so i was applying specific converters for my queries
List<Document> results = dao.find(CollectionNames.PESSOA_JURIDICA, filter(search), ascending(sortBy), limit, offset);
        return results.stream().map(d -> converter.read(PessoaJuridicaDocument.class, d)).collect(Collectors.toList());

see org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter for details

Comment: What is the converter class here? Can you add an answer so that I can accept it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converter class can help you on that:

```
package simple.sample.mongo.dao;

import com.mongodb.client.model.Filters;
import com.mongodb.client.model.Sorts;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import simple.sample.mongo.dao.base.BaseDAO;
import simple.sample.mongo.models.TodoDocument;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Component
public class TodoDAO {

    private final MappingMongoConverter converter;
    private final BaseDAO dao;

    public TodoDAO(MappingMongoConverter converter, BaseDAO dao) {
        this.converter = converter;
        this.dao = dao;
    }

    // see for more converters https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-examples/tree/main/mongodb/example/src/main/java/example/springdata/mongodb/converters
    public List<TodoDocument> find(String description) {
        return dao.find("todos",
                        Filters.regex("description", description),
                        Sorts.ascending("description"), 100, 0)
                .stream().map(doc -> converter.read(TodoDocument.class, doc))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

}
```

Where `TodoDocument` is a mongo collection mapped to java class.

You can either use `TodoRepository` to query the document store or get connection from `MongoTemplate` in order to get access to more flexible queries.

The more complete sourcecode can be found [in this link](https://github.com/sombriks/simple-sample-mongo)